# Перенаправление со всех доменов с http на https

Tags: .htaccess, https

Задача:
— имеем штук 8 доменов. Каждый имеет вид с www и без. Главный домен у нас с www и с https.

Перенаправляем все домены на основной с помощью правила:
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.main.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.main.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Всё работает, если вводить http://notmain1.ru, то переводится на https://www.main.com

Но если ввести http**S**://notmain1.ru, то переход на основной домен не работает. Т.е. по факту корректно работает только для протокола http.

Вопрос — как создать аналогичное правило на перенаправление всех доменов с https на основной https?

Comment: ВОт твой ответ https://asterios.ws/java_source/post/39052
Смотри вроде так

Comment: Не оно. Нужно конкретно перенаправлять все домены с https на основной https.